# Convert any column in a data frame with numbers to a numeric value (is.numeric)

Tags: r

I have a large data frame and it's a mixture of character, integer, and numeric columns. From what I've seen, some columns that I want to be numeric are not always numeric. I can manually convert each one but I wanted to see if there was a way to detect a column with numbers in it and then convert it to numeric.

Comment: Is this some table you are reading from a source? If it is, `read.table()` should automatically do it for you. The data frame will have numeric columns as well as factors. To avoid factors, you can use `as.is=T`, then you will get numeric and character columns.

Comment: If R is guessing that some of your columns are character when they should be numeric, I would be very careful about using `as.numeric()` because you may have something R does not recognize in an otherwise valad entry. `as.numeric()` will convert that to `NA`. Check one of your conversions for `NA`s and make sure they are all correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an lapply if you first create a vector of the column names with numbers in them. You will likely need to create this vector of column names manually, versus creating it based upon searching for columns using `is.numeric`, as your issue is that they are incorrectly classified. This is using `library(data.table)`.

```
cols <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))), .SDcols=cols]
```